# In PJSIP, how can I check if a pj_str_t has out of range pointer or length before converting to an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, pjsip

In PJSIP, a pj_str_t is defined as:

`typedef struct pj_str_t pj_str_t;`

Which expands to:

```
struct pj_str_t
{
    /** Buffer pointer, which is by convention NOT null terminated. */
    char       *ptr;

    /** The length of the string. */
    pj_ssize_t  slen;
};
```

The problem is that sometimes, checking a pj_str_t's ->ptr and ->slen result in something like 54,693,715 for slen and out of range pointer too.  These, however are sometimes less than PJ_MAXINT32  0x7FFFFFFFL = 2,147,483,647.

If I do attempt to convert the pj_str_t to an NSString when the values are out of expected using this approach

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:myPjString->ptr length:myPjString->slen encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Xcode will naturally crash throwing a malloc exception or a bad access.

How can I check if the `pj_str_t`'s data (I assume ptr and slen) is valid to be converted to an NString?

Thanks in advance.

I found this out when examining our acc_info variable that is a `pjsua_acc_info` struct (http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__acc__info.htm).  What I found is that when the iOS device is offline, or has just been turned online and has not yet re-established a connection to the SIP server, that the acc_info struct has a bunch of variables that are `pj_str_t`s, `pj_bool`s, `pjsip_status_code`. For `pj_str_t`, it is a struct that points to char * and slen.

When a value for a `pj_str_t` is valid, I can see that ptr points to a valid char * sequence of slen length and they are chars (from within the Xcode debugger).

When a value for `pj_str_t` isn't valid, I am seeing several things.  Xcode's debugger displays the ptr and slen with these observed values:

```
ptr `0x116fdfd40` (4,680,711,488)
ptr "" sometimes if slen is > the PJ_MAXINT32 2,147,483,647
ptr "@4\xb4(" and an slen of 54,693,715 < PJ_MAXINT32
ptr '\x98' and an slen of 621,138,593 < PJ_MAXINT32
ptr 3,220,940,300 and an slen of 3,220,940,304
```

These are clearly out of range, but what I don't know is "how can I detect that these are our of range?"

and 
    ptr 0xbffba5f4 (3,220,940,276) and an slen of 0xbffba5f8 (3,220,940,276)
For the last line of output

po &acc_info.acc_uri.ptr
0xbffba5f4
3,220,940,276

po &acc_info.acc_uri.slen
0xbffba5f8
3,220,940,280

Even though these are both > than PJ_MAXINT32, 2,147,483,647, there are examples above that are < PJ_MAXINT32 but still clearly out of range and as we can see, only 4 integers apart from each other.

Since ptr of a pj_str_t is a pointer to char *, how can I check if the value of the ptr pointer address is numerically close to the value of slen?

I'm using this in Objective-C:

if (myPjString->ptr == NULL || myPjString->slen >= PJ_MAXINT32 )

I can't do an `if (myPjString->ptr >= some int)` because that triggers an error of `Ordered comparison between pointer and integer (char * and long)`.

I've got multiple things I'd like to try but don't know C well enough to do.

Thanks for your time on this one.

Comment: What are these cases in which `slen` is a crazy value? Even the max length being 2^32-1 is way too large... If you've got memory corruption, all bets are off the table, and you should fix that issue before doing anything else.

Comment: Question updated above.  Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/169394/itai-ferber

Comment: Looks like when you inspect these values, they're set to garbage — either they haven't been initialized, or the PJSIP library is happy to write garbage into them. There will be almost no good way to tell that these things are valid: there's no way to tell if a given pointer points to anything reasonable, or whether it points to a buffer that is not shorter than the string length... You will have to find a different way to tell if the SIP server is in a valid state, and only then inspect these values.